# Failed to load ApplicationContext Error in Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a BooResourcesT test class from within IntelliJ Idea and I am getting the "Failed to load ApplicationContext" exception.

**Please look at my code::**

```
    package lms.co;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.hasItems;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lms.co.controller.BooksResourceImpl;
import lms.co.model.Book;
import lms.co.repository.BookRepository;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = LMSApplication.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class BooksResourceITTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository booksRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    private BooksResourceImpl booksResource;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        booksResource = new BooksResourceImpl();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(booksResource).build();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(booksResource, "booksRepo", booksRepo);
    }

    @Test
    public void addBookTest() throws Exception{
        Book book = new Book("isbn1","Test1","Test Author","","","","","");
        
        String body = mapper.writeValueAsString(book);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/book")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(body))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }

    @Test
    public void getBookByIsbnTest() throws Exception {
        Book book = new Book("isbn2","Test2","Test Author","","","","","");
        booksRepo.addBook(book);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/book/isbn2")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title",is("Test2")))
                .andReturn();
    }

    @Test
    public void getBooksTest() throws Exception {
        Book book1 = new Book("isbn3","Test3","Test Author","","","","","");
        booksRepo.addBook(book1);
        Book book2 = new Book("isbn4","Test4","Test Author","","","","","");
        booksRepo.addBook(book2);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/books")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[*].title", hasItems("Test4", "Test3")))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

**Error is**

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)

    ... 56 more
```

I am new in spring project and this is my 1st time of getting this type error so please help me and please don't close my question if their is an para mistakes.Please...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception